# Python to get onclick values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python and BeautifulSoup to scrape a web page for a small project of mine. The webpage has multiple entries, each separated by a table row in HTML. My code partially works however a lot of the output is blank and it won't fetch all of the results from the web page or even gather them into the same line.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Website</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<td class=channel>Artist</td><td class=channel>Title</td><td class=channel>Date</td><td class=channel>Time</td></tr>
<tr><td>35</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td><a href="#" onClick="searchDB('LoremIpsum','FooWorld')">FooWorld</a></td><td>12/10/2014</td><td>2:53:17 PM</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to only extract the values from the onclick action 'searchDB', so for example 'LoremIpsum' and 'FooWorld' are the only two results that I want.

Here is the code that I've written. So far, it properly pulls some of the write values, but sometimes the values are empty.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

html = response.read()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

properties = soup.findAll('a', onclick=True)

for eachproperty in properties:
    print re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9]*)'", eachproperty['onclick'])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the input you've provided, it prints `['LoremIpsum', 'FooWorld']`, which is what you wanted, right? Then, what is the problem? Please provide an HTML input that gives you troubles parsing. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> for x in soup.find_all('a'):    # will give you all a tag
...     try:
...         if re.match('searchDB',x['onclick']):    # if onclick attribute exist, it will match for searchDB, if success will print
...             print x['onclick']        # here you can do your stuff instead of print
...     except:pass
... 
searchDB('LoremIpsum','FooWorld')
```

instead of print you can save it to some variable like

```
>>> k = x['onclick']
>>> re.findall("'(\w+)'",k)
['LoremIpsum', 'FooWorld']
```

`\w` is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: Thank you so much for your code, it's a fantastic improvement! This is EXACTLY how I need it to be... However, I still get "searchDB" in my results.. I'm sure I'll figure out how to remove that.

Comment: Silencing all exceptions is generally an unwise thing to do. In this case, `KeyError` would suffice.

Comment: if you know what you doing, then its not a problem, yep we don't want the 'a' tag that doesnt  has onclick attribute

Comment: I upvoted you, for what it's worth. I'm still trying to figure out how to parse this damn "searchDB" from the output lol

Comment: @FairlightEvony i have given the solution for that too

Comment: I had to find another way of doing it since i'm working with arrays but I did get it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`or row in rows[1:]:
            cols = row.findAll('td')
            link = cols[1].find('a').get('onclick')`

Comment: That's the correct answer